# best and convenient way to upgrade the django project from older version to latest version

Tags: django

I want to upgrade my django project from django 1.3 to django 1.5. How can i do that.

Right now i am facing lots of trouble to solve this. And i don't want to use the virtual environment for old version. Because on server its causing lots of trouble. Can anyone provide me the step by step process for the same.

Error i am getting:

```
502 Bad Gateway

nginx/1.4.4
```

Comment: Does your application is compatible with Django 1.5? Did you test it locally?

Comment: Application is developed in 1.3 and while running that in 1.5 throws errors

Comment: possible duplicate of [upgrading python django project 1.3 to 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914494/upgrading-python-django-project-1-3-to-1-5)

Comment: You can't change django version, just like that. Django 1.4 and 1.5 has incompatible backwards changes, and I'm pretty sure that you will have to rewrite some code in your application. [Django 1.4 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/), [Django 1.5 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/)